# How to create dynamic table in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just want to create dynamic table.
In the pictures

[image]

[image]

I can add or delete rows like this.

But, how to add or delete a column in Unity. Is this possible?
Please give me a hand.

Comment: What table do you want ? In UI or something else?

Comment: What have you researched so far? It's completely unclear what you are asking

Comment: Okay! I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I'm going to explain how to create a dynamic vertical list. From there you can use this to create your table. Here is the UI object setup that I use

1. Holder object(This has a Image and a ScrollRect component)
   1.1 ViePortObject(this has a Image and mask component, use this object
   to define the size of the vieport)

   1.1.1 ContentObject(you spawn your elements as children of this object and it holds the Vertical List script)

And here is the actual script for you to use:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class VerticalList : VerticalLayoutGroup {
        public override void CalculateLayoutInputVertical()
        {
            base.CalculateLayoutInputVertical();
            rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(rectTransform.sizeDelta.x, minHeight);
        }

    }
```

Here is a screenshot of how the hierarchy looks like.

[image]

Edit:
You will also need a prefab with a Layout Element component that you instantiate as a child of the ContentObject.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot!! You save my life.^^

Answer (score -3):

You can use [this asset](http://u3d.as/1rag?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=txt&utm_campaign=howtocreatedynamic) to draw a table based on any collection. You just select the elements' properties you want for the columns and it's filled automatically.

[http://u3d.as/1rag](http://u3d.as/1rag?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=txt&utm_campaign=howtocreatedynamic)

Here is a little demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jS2fdA5tdYM

Comment: This is a [link-only question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers). Please include the relevant link content in your answer.